# Anyone know how to change username and password with strophe.js?

Tags: xmpp, strophe, strophe.js

I am building an XMPP chat app, I used strophe.js but I have no idea of how to change username and password with strophe. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change **username**, because it is the JID, a unique identifier of the user, created on registration to your XMPP server.

On the contrary you can change the **password** according to [xep-0077 - In-Band Registration](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html#registrar-formtypes-changepassword).

Using Strophe.js the code is:

```
function setPwd(pwd) {
    // jid is user account (i.e. myname@server.com)
    // name is user name (i.e. myname), must be equal to first part of jid
    var iq = $iq({
        type: 'set',
        to: jid,
        }).c('query', {
            xmlns: 'jabber:iq:register'
        })
        .c('username').t(name).up()
        .c('password').t(pwd);
    connection.sendIQ(iq, function(iq) {
        console.log("setPwd-callback", iq);
    });
}
```